# Личные сообщения php&mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте, появилась необходимость сделать личные сообщения. Я представил как это сделать, вот только думаю: допустим есть таблица messages, там поля subjectTO,subjectMe,text,date вот мне кажется что так делать не правильно, допустим есть 20000 сообщений, вот будет долго выводить их, там пока цикл пробежится по ним пройдёт большое кол-во времени, а если миллион? посоветуйте что и как лучше, буду очень признательны!

Comment: Какой цикл пробежится? Индексируйте поля.

Answer (score 1):

В таблице messages у вас должны быть поля:

- sender_id - идентификатор отправителя
- receiver_id - идентификатор получателя
- message - собственно само сообщение
- created - дата создания

Соответственно отправленные сообщения можно выбрать:

```
SELECT * FROM messages where sender_id=<идентификатор отправителя>
```

З.Ы. на самом деле это не самая оптимальная(по скорости) структура, но я не думаю если вы задаете такие вопросы вам не потребуется эта оптимизация. Преждевременная оптимизация это зло.

Answer (score 1):

Таблица messages :

- sender_id - отправитель
- receiver_id - получатель
- message - текст сообщения
- status - прочтено / не прочтено
- datetime - дата создания
- Элемент списка

И собственно выборка :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM messages WHERE receiver_id=<идентификатор получателя> and status='unread'
```

смотрим если есть сообщения адресованые текущему пользователю и которые не были прочтены